# When in render mode, my objects don't show up

Tags: rendering

When I enter rendering mode, there is just a gray screen as the final render, with none of my objects showing. I tried to look up videos on YT but all of them were either old or older versions of blender. The UI is different from then so it's very confusing to me as to how I'm going to make my objects show in the rendering mode.

Comment: Are you rendering with your graphics card? are you using cycles or eevee.

Comment: I am using evee.

Comment: Is your graphics card compatible with blender?

Comment: The minimum requirements for Blender 2.8 can be found here: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Answer (score 0):

For starters, make sure that your objects are enabled to be visible in render and viewport. Also make sure enough light is in your seen for you to be able to see them.